# Why is a bias neuron necessary for a backpropagating neural network that recognizes the XOR operator?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, xor, backpropagation, bias-neuron

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031769/training-a-neural-network-via-backpropagation-for-the-xor-operator-error-calcul) yesterday regarding issues that I was having with my backpropagating neural network for the XOR operator. I did a little more work and realized that it may have to do with not having a bias neuron.

My question is, what is the role of the bias neuron in general, and what is its role in a backpropagating neural network that recognizes the XOR operator? Is it possible to create one without a bias neuron?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)

Comment: you may be interested in this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561182/neural-network-xor-gate-not-learning/38767930#38767930

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to create a neural network without a bias neuron... it would work just fine, but for more information I would recommend you see the answers to this question:

[Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)

**Update:**
the role of the bias neuron in the neural net that attempts to <strike>solve</strike> model XOR is to minimize the size of the neural net. Usually, for "primitive" (not sure if this is the correct term) logic functions such as `AND`, `OR`, `NAND`, etc, you are trying to create a neural network with 2 input neurons, 2 hidden neurons and 1 output neuron. This can't be done for `XOR` because the simplest way you can model an `XOR` is with two `NAND`s:

[image]

You can consider `A` and `B` as your input neurons, the gate in the middle is your "bias" neuron, the two gates following are your "hidden" neurons and finally you have the output neuron. You can solve `XOR` without having a bias neuron, but it would require that you increase the number of hidden neurons to a minimum of 3 hidden neurons. In this case, the 3rd neuron essentially acts as a bias neuron.  Here is another question that discusses the bias neuron with regards to `XOR`: [XOR problem solvable with 2x2x1 neural network without bias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893311/xor-problem-solvable-with-2x2x1-neural-network-without-bias)

Comment: I just saw that after posting this question, but I'm also curious about the specific role of the bias neuron for XOR.